# Why the java JDK cannot print out proper message in my terminal

Tags: java

I just installed Java 11 on my windows 10 laptop. And it cannot print out a proper message when I called java.

```
   ???java [options] <??> [args...]
           ?????
   ?  java [options] -jar <jar ??> [args...]
           ??? jar ???
   ?  java [options] -m <??>[/<??>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <??>[/<??>] [args...]
           ??????????
   ?  java [options] <???> [args]
           ???????????

 ????????-jar <jar ??>?-m ?
 --module <??>/<??> ????????
 ??????

 ????????
```

Error screenshot

[image]

Some wired things happened.. How do I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> try this command and restart cmd.

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%"SystemRoot"%_system32_cmd.exe /v CodePage /t REG_DWORD /d 936 /f
```